# Select the row which has less value from the row

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Question tiitle might be confusing but here is what I am trying to do, I have a query :

```
select * from mytable where days between 1 and 21
```

I am getting `7` records for this, In these records, there is one user who has 2 classes which are in `21` and `7`, i am trying to use the second record as my record to reach the day to 21 so it can send email. because this user has two classes going on, i want its always latest class to be considered ignoring the first one.

Cannot use the group by because there are some fields which are different and they cannot be removed like `ID, teacher` etc

Second scenario is, the user can have only one class running at a time so probably in that case, my query works fine

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help clarify what you want.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rvSXQDWA

Comment: Why should you pick that record if it's not between 1 and 21? Where is the date field in your sample data? Do you know what you want?

Comment: Your sample makes no sense in relation to your question. You stated class in 7 and 21. But there is nothing in your pastebin like that. Why should it select the row you stated it should select and not others?

Comment: Updated my Question & Paste https://pastebin.com/3DsZWkTJ

Comment: Why pick 7 instead of 21?

Answer (score 2):

In your data you have two columns name ID, I mean the ID allow you determinate which one is the latest.

Also you should have a way to identify each student, in this case I use the email address because multiple student can have same name.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY EmailAddress ORDER BY ID DESC) as rn
       FROM yourTable
     ) as t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```